# How to inverse a whole cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, inverse

I have one cell array A= {<2x6 double>,<4x6 double>,<43x6 doubl>}. and now I want to calculate the inverse value of each matrix elements inside the cell array. I have written below code but It doesn't work.

```
C = cellfun(@inv, A, 'Un', false);
```

can you please guide me how can I write the proper code? e.g the element inside of the cell array is 2 and I want to show the inverse of this value like 1/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`inv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html) is the matrix inverse, which will give you the error `Matrix must be square`, as it tries to invert the three matrices inside of `A`. You probably want element-wise division: `1./X`

```
C = cellfun(@(X) 1./X, A, 'Un', false);
```